# Delete GitLab environment from pipeline job

Tags: gitlab-ci, cicd, gitlab-pipelines, gitlab-ci.yml

Currently, I am creating GitLab environments for each merge request to deploy temporary pages. These environments stop as soon as merge request is merged, but I want to add an additional step to the pipeline to "Remove environment" completely from "Stopped" environments. I don't want to use GUI and only option I found was an API method:

`DELETE /projects/:id/environments/:environment_id`

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/environments.html#delete-an-environment

But, problem here is that it required `:environment_id` variable, which I couldn't manage to find and get.

Any help with a different approach or how to get `:environment_id` will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can [schedule for deletion](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/environments.html#delete-multiple-stopped-review-apps) all stopped review apps environment :

```
DELETE /projects/:id/environments/review_apps
```

Or you can [list your environments](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/environments.html#list-environments) and search for the one you need to delete with `name` or `search` param. Then you can get the `environment_id` to delete that environment. You can add the `states` param to get only stopped environments :

```
GET /projects/:id/environments?states=stopped&name=review%2Fxxx
```

Then just make a loop on the result to call the `DELETE` endpoint. You can use [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to get the `environment_id` in the result.

Comment: That is using the API, but I don't have an opportunity to use JavaScript. Only pipeline scripts :(

Comment: You can make some api call during the pipeline script. And you mentionned API, that is why I suggest you to use it.